# Understanding mean in Poisson Processes

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Assuming I have a question like :

- Suppose that the amount of time one spends in a bank is exponentially
  distributed with mean ten minutes, that is, $λ = 1/10$. What is the
  probability that a customer will spend more than fifteen minutes in the bank?
  What is the probability that a customer will spend more than fifteen minutes in
  the bank given that she is still in the bank after ten minutes?

What I don't understand is the mean, if it's given that $λ=1/10$ which is $0.1$, does it mean we have $.1$ customers arriving every $10$ minutes ? It's a bit confusing to me and is my first solution correct?

$$\Pr[K>15] = e^{(-10)(0.1)}\frac{\big((10)(0.1)\big)^{15}}{15!}$$

Comment: It means one customer per 10 minutes on average. If it was 2 customers per 10 minutes it will be 0.2? so it is how many customers a minute.

Comment: The probability the customer will spend more than $15$ minutes is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas please can you shed a little light on what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use Poisson processes here — this question is about the use of the exponential distribution, and its property of [memorylessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness). For $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$, $\mathbb{E} X = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ (so indeed here the rate is $\lambda=\frac{1}{10}$), you have
$$
\Pr[X > t ] = 1-F_X(t) = e^{-\lambda t}
$$
and for $t \geq s \geq 0$
$$
\Pr[X > t \mid X  \geq s] = \Pr[X > t-s ] = e^{-\lambda (t-s)}\ .
$$
For $t=15$ and $s=10$, you get 
$$
\Pr[X > 15 ] = e^{-\frac{15}{10}} = e^{-\frac{3}{2}}, \qquad 
\Pr[X > 15 \mid X  \geq 10] = e^{-\frac{5}{10}}= e^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ .
$$

---

As for the parameter $\lambda$ in Poisson process, this is the *rate* (rate of "events") -- that is, in an interval of time of length $\tau$, if $N=(N_t)_{t>0}$ is a counting Poisson process with  rate $\lambda$, the expected number of increments is going to be $\lambda\tau$: $\mathbb{E}[N_{t+\tau} - N_t]= \lambda\tau$ (there is "one increment every $1/\tau$ units of time").